# Rounding time in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, c

I got the following code:

```
    int days = round(durationTimeInterval / D_DAY);
    int secondsLeft = durationTimeInterval - (days * D_DAY);    
    double hoursLeft = secondsLeft % D_HOUR;
    double hours = round(hoursLeft);
```

if seconds left is 10710 then dividing by D_HOUR give me 2,975 I then want to round that up to 3 hours... Am not sure how to do this? Please advise.

Comment: can you detail your question a bit more?

Comment: I'm with phoxis on this one? You want to round to the nearest 3rd hour? What does that mean? Maybe start with what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the round function or ceil function:

[ROUND](http://www.codecogs.com/reference/c/math.h/round.php)
[CEIL](http://www.codecogs.com/reference/c/math.h/ceil.php)